# Unity WheelJoint2D will not rotate when increasing motor speed

Tags: unity, physics

I have a wheel joint 2D attached to a game object in Unity:

[image: Wheel Components]

In its associated wheel script I am increasing the motor speed as described in the [tutorial](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-WheelJoint2D.html).

```
public class Wheel : MonoBehaviour
{
    WheelJoint2D wheel;
    JointMotor2D motor;

    void Start()
    {
        wheel = GetComponent<WheelJoint2D>();
        motor = wheel.motor;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            motor.motorSpeed += 10;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            motor.motorSpeed -= 10;

        //Debug.Log(motor.motorSpeed);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the sprite does not rotate and I am not certain as to why?

Does the wheel joint have to be attached to another rigid body in order to function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to attach the `wheeljoint2d` to another sprite wich with a rigidbody2d for it to work. So yes, you should attach it to another `rigidbody2d`.